# Is there a way to determine if an exe is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: powershell

I have a exe and when i run the exe I can see under the Platform column in Task Manager that it is 64 bit.
Is there a way I can determine this without having to run the app ?
I have looked at Powershell and seen this , but it comes up as 32 which is wrong ?

```
$FilePath = "C:\Program Files\UsersApp\userdetailsCfg.exe"

[int32]$MACHINE_OFFSET = 4
[int32]$PE_POINTER_OFFSET = 60

[byte[]]$data = New-Object -TypeName System.Byte[] -ArgumentList 4096
$stream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList ($FilePath, 'Open', 'Read')
$stream.Read($data, 0, 4096) | Out-Null

[int32]$PE_HEADER_ADDR = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($data, $PE_POINTER_OFFSET)
[int32]$machineUint = [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt16($data, $PE_HEADER_ADDR + $MACHINE_OFFSET)
$stream.Close()

$result = "" | select FilePath, FileType, Is64Bit
$result.FilePath = $FilePath
$result.Is64Bit = $false

switch ($machineUint) 
{
    0      { $result.FileType = 'Native' }
    0x014c { $result.FileType = 'x86' }
    0x0200 { $result.FileType = 'Itanium' }
    0x8664 { $result.FileType = 'x64'; $result.is64Bit = $true; }
}
$result
```

Comment: What is the use case for digging at this? If you are on an x64 system, then, x32, runs has as x64 would.

Comment: @postanote A workaround for fixing an issue with an application our company is using differentiates between x86 and x64, so I need to know which architecture is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task Manager is not the only option to check for bitness.

There are MS SysInternals tools. Specifically, `sigcheck.exe`.

> Sigcheck is a command-line utility that shows file version number, timestamp information, and digital signature details, including certificate chains. It also includes an option to check a file’s status on VirusTotal, a site that performs automated file scanning against over 40 antivirus engines, and an option to upload a file for > scanning.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck

Other ways, including the above, are discussed here - reference:

[How to Check if a Program (.EXE or .DLL) is 32-bit or 64-bit](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-out-if-a-program-exe-file-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/#:%7E:text=exe%20file%20using%20Notepad%20to%20check%20its%20headers.,for%20the%201st%20occurrence%20of%20the%20word%20PE)

All over the web, there are pre-built Powershell scripts for bitness checks that you can use as-is or tweak as needed.

> [PowerShell: Get-FileBitness](https://gist.github.com/MyITGuy/a0d462a6e218d1e5a940)
>
> [PSTip How to determine if a file is 32-bit or 64-bit](https://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/03/08/pstip-how-to-determine-if-a-file-is-32bit-or-64bit/)

```
$MACHINE_OFFSET = 4
$PE_POINTER_OFFSET = 60
$MachineType = Write-Output Native I386 Itanium x64
 
$filePath = "$env:windir\notepad.exe"
$data = New-Object System.Byte[] 4096
$stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream -ArgumentList $filePath,Open,Read
$stream.Read($data,0,$PE_POINTER_OFFSET) | Out-Null
$PE_HEADER_ADDR = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($data, $PE_POINTER_OFFSET)
$machineUint = [System.BitConverter]::ToUInt16($data, $PE_HEADER_ADDR + $MACHINE_OFFSET)
$MachineType[$machineUint]
```

> [Get-BinaryType function Finds bitness of .exe with Powershell](https://gist.github.com/MattUebel/2292484)

Comment: That doesnt work as expected. If i run the script it returns 32bit, but when i run the app and look in taks manager it is 64bit.

Comment: It also disagrees with 7Zip for me on a particular .exe.     This scripts shows the .exe as x64, while 7zip shows it as x86.  I expect x86.  Another .dll has the same experience: I expect x86, this script shows x64, while 7zip and DependenciesGUI both show x86.

Comment: @orionelenzil you should specify what 'it' is, there are like 5 different ways described in the question, which fails? `sigcheck` should do the correct thing?

Comment: @stijn - ugh, you're right. And now at this remove I can't tell which one I meant.  There might be some value in it to someone in the future, so I'll leave it.